# Sequencial chracterisation of $\limsup f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am trying to understand the definition of $\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)$. There is a Wikipedia article that gives quite a few definitions. One of them is:
[image]

I think I understand it more or less. However, I came across the following post [definition of limsup of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533872/definition-of-limsup-of-a-function). There it is said that $\limsup f(x)$ can be characterised in terms of sequences in the following way:
[image]

I tried to prove it, but I got stuck. I also tried to find a book that explains it, but I could't find a single book that covers $\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)$.**Does anybody have any books that talk about it?**

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**DEFINITION**
Suppose $X$ is a metric space, $E\subset X$, $f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^1$,
and $p$ is a limit point of $E$.
Define a set $L$ of extended real numbers as follows: If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence
in $E$ converging to $p$ with $p_n\not=p$, and if $f(p_{n_k})\rightarrow l$
for some subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}$, then $l\in L$.
Put

$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\sup L$$

and

$$\liminf_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\inf L\mbox{.}$$

In other words, $\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ is defined to be the supremum of the set consisting of $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(p_n)$, where $p_n\rightarrow p$, $p_n\not=p$. (Note that $\sup\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha=\sup\{\sup E_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$.)

**THEOREM 1**
(a) If $y>\limsup_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$f(x)<y$ whenever $0<d(x,p)<\delta$, $x\in E$. 
(b) If $y<\lim\sup_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$, then for every $\delta>0$, there exists
$x\in E$ with $0<d(x,p)<\delta$, such that $f(x)>y\mbox{.}$
A similar result is valid for $\liminf$.

**PROOF**
(a) Suppose to every $\delta>0$ corresponds $x\in E$ such that $0<d(x,p)<\delta$
and $f(x)\geq y$. Take $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$, $n=1,2,3...$. We then obtain a sequence
$x_n\rightarrow p$, $x_n\not=p$ such that

$$f(x_n)\geq y\mbox{.}$$

Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we get

$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)\geq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)\geq y\mbox{.}$$

This proves (a).
(b) Since $y<\sup L$, $l>y$ for some $l\in L$, which means that there exists a sequence
$x_n\rightarrow p$, $x_n\not=p$ such that $f(x_n)\rightarrow l$. Since $l>y$, $f(x_n)>y$
for all $n$ from some definite index $N$ onwards. For any $\delta>0$, there exists $n>N$
such that $0<d(p,x_n)<\delta$, since $x_n\rightarrow p$. Evidently, $f(x_n)>y$. $\square$

**THEOREM 2**
If $\liminf_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\limsup_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=l$, then $f(x)\rightarrow l$
as $x\rightarrow p$.

**PROOF**
This follows immediately from Theorem 1(a).

**THEOREM 3**
If $g$ is another mapping of $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^1$, and if there exists $\delta>0$ such
that $0<d(p,x)<\delta$, $x\in E$ imply that

$$\tag{1}f(x)\leq g(x)\mbox{,}$$

then

$$\tag{2}\liminf f(x)\leq\liminf g(x)\mbox{,}$$

$$\tag{3}\limsup f(x)\leq\limsup g(x)\mbox{,}$$

as $x\rightarrow p$.

**PROOF**
We show (3). If $\limsup f(x)>y>\limsup g(x)$, then, by Theorem 1, there exist $\delta>\delta'>0$
such that

$$\tag{4}g(x)<y\quad(x\in E,0<d(x,p)<\delta')\mbox{;}$$

also, there exists $\xi\in E$ with $0<d(\xi,p)<\delta'$ such that

$$\tag{5}f(\xi)>y\mbox{.}$$

(4) and (5) contradict (1).

**THEOREM 4**
If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=l$, then
$$\tag{6}\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=l\mbox{.}$$

**PROOF**
Let $p_n\rightarrow p$ with $p_n\not=p$. Then $f(p_n)\rightarrow l$, so that
$$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(p_n)=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(p_n)=l\mbox{.}$$
Since $\{p_n\}$ is arbitrary, (6) follows.

Comment: Theorem 1 implies this definition is equivalent to that provided by Wikipedia

Comment: Okay, thats more work than I expected. Thanks! Do you have a book recomendation? I think I need to do a little bit more reading.

Comment: I don't know if there is a book using this definition. This is just a generalization of Rudin's definition and theorems on limit superior of sequences worked out by me.

Comment: I see. I had a look at Rudin's book. Did you use a sequence like $y_{k}:=f(x_{k})$?

Comment: No. When I refer to sequence of function values of sequence $\{x_n\}$ is the domain of $f$, I write $\{f(x_n)\}$ or $f(x_n)\rightarrow l$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Could you explain the two lines above theorem 1 a little bit further, please? As I understand it we have $l=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(p_{n_{k}})=\limsup_{k\to\infty}f(p_{n_{k}})$, since the limit exists. Isn't it sort of "always save to say" lets consider $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$, since it always exists,i.e. it is either finite or $\infty,-\infty$? At what point do you use $\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} E_{\alpha}=\sup\{\sup E_{\alpha}:\alpha\in A\}$?

Comment: Is $L=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}$, if $E_{\alpha}$ is the set of all subsequential limits of $f(p_{n}^{\alpha})$? Furthermore $\limsup_{k\to\infty}f(p_{k}^{\alpha})=\sup E_{\alpha}$? Then $\sup L=\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}=\sup\{\sup E_{\alpha}:\alpha\in A\}=\sup\{\limsup_{k\to\infty}f(p_{k}^{\alpha}):\alpha\in A\}$?Hence, it is the supremum of the set consisting of $\limsup_{k\to\infty}f(p_{k}^{\alpha})$.

Comment: I also tried to show the equivalence of the two definitions here. It is a bit lengthy I guess, but I would really appreciate if you had a look at it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341203/show-equivalence-of-definitons-of-limsup-fx . Many thanks in advance and merry christmas! :)