# Show equivalence of definitons of $\limsup f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

This is a follow up question to the following question I asked. [Sequencial chracterisation of $\limsup f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340107/sequencial-chracterisation-of-limsup-fx/4340323?noredirect=1#comment9055071_4340323) .

**I would like to pove that**
[image]

**is equivalent to**
[image]

**Proof attempt**

"$\Leftarrow$"

Let $\eta>0$. Consider $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}$ and $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}$. By thm. 1 (see below) we know that there is $\delta_{1}>0$ s.t. $f(x)<\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}$ and $\delta_{2}>0$ s.t. $f(x)>\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}$.

Define $\tilde{\delta}:=\min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ and consider $\epsilon<\tilde{\delta}$. Then we have that

$\begin{equation} \limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}<f(x)<\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}\end{equation}$, $x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}$, since
$E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\subset E\cap B_{\tilde{\delta}}(a)\setminus\{a\}$ and thus $|x|<\tilde{\delta}$.

Therefore $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}$ is an upper bound for $f$ on $E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}$ and $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}$ is a lower bound.
Hence, we get the following chain of inequalities:

$$\begin{align}\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}&\leq\inf\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}\\ & \leq f(x)\leq\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}\\ &\leq\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}\end{align}$$.

Hence,

\begin{align}\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\eta<\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)-\frac{\eta}{2}&\leq\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}\\ &\leq\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\frac{\eta}{2}\\ &<\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)+\eta\\ &\iff |\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}-\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)|<\eta\end{align}.

In other words we have that
\begin{align}\forall\eta>0\exists\delta>0\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}:|\epsilon|<\delta &\implies |\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}-\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)|<\eta\\ &\iff \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}g(\epsilon)=\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)&,\\ & g(\epsilon):=\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}\end{align}.

"$\implies$"

This direction is essentially done in "Introdunction to Mathematical Analysis" by Beatriz Laferriere, Gerado Laferriere,Nguyen Mau Nam.

Link: https://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1003&context=pdxopen

There the following is stated:

[image]
[image]

i) From the first three lines of the Corollary I would conclude that $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\in A$. Thus, $A\neq\emptyset$

ii) The rest implies that $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ is an upper bound of $A$. Therefore $\sup A$ exists.

Because $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\in A$ we have $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\leq\sup A$. But we also have that $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ is an upper bound. Thus $\sup A\leq\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$.Hence,
$$\begin{align}\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\leq\sup A\leq\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\end{align}\iff\sup A=\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$$

But since $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)\in A$ we have that $\sup A=\max A$.

I hope it makes sense. It my be a bit overly detailed. Is there a shorter proof?

Many thanks in advacne!

---

**Theorems used:**
[image]

Comment: You only need to show that there exists exactly one number satisfying Theorem 1.

Comment: Which number are you referring to? $\delta$, $x$ or $y$? My guess is $y$. But how does uniquness help? Wouldn't you have to show first that $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ in the "other definition" satisfies this condition as well?  What about my solution? I had a look at it agian and I would say that the choice of $\tilde{\delta}$ is not necessary, since $(b)$ says "$\forall\delta>0$", which I apperently I did not notice.

Comment: @user912011 I tried to show uniqueness here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341871/show-that-limsup-x-to-pfx-is-the-unique-element-which-satisfies-a-certai