# Show that $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ is the unique element, which satisfies a certain condition.(follow-up question )

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

This is follow up question of the following two questions I asked

- [Sequencial chracterisation of $\limsup f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340107/sequencial-chracterisation-of-limsup-fx/4340323?noredirect=1#comment9055071_4340323)
- [Show equivalence of definitons of $\limsup f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341203/show-equivalence-of-definitons-of-limsup-fx?noredirect=1#comment9057054_4341203)

I would like to show that there is $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ is the unique real number, which satifies:
[image]

**Proof:**

Suppose there is $c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. conditions $a)$ and $b)$ are satisfied and $c\neq\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$. W.l.o.g. suppose $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)>c$

By condition $a)$ we have that there is $\tilde{\delta}$ such that $\forall x\in B_{\tilde{\delta}}(p): f(x)<c$.

But since $c$ satisfies both $a)$ and $b)$ too, it follows by condition $b)$ that

$$\begin{align}\forall\delta>0\exists x_{\delta}\in B_{\delta}(p): f(x_{\delta})>c \end{align}$$

Thus, for $\tilde{\delta}$ there is $x_{\tilde{\delta}}$ s.t. $f(x_{\tilde{\delta}})>c$.

$x_{\tilde{\delta}}\in B_{\tilde{\delta}}(p)$. Therefore $f(x_{\tilde{\delta}})<c$.Therefore

$$\begin{align}c<f(x_{\tilde{\delta}})<c\end{align}$$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ is the unique element satisfying $a)$ and $b)$.

---

[image]

Comment: You are confused. You must show that if $y_0$ is a number so that:  [(a) for all $y>y_0$ you have that there is a $\delta$ so that $f(x)<y$ for all $x\in B_\delta(p)$ and (b) for all $y<y_0$ and $\delta>0$ there is a $x\in B_\delta(p)$ so that $f(x)>y$] then $y_0=\limsup_{x\to p} f(x)$. What you have shown is that if there is a $y_0$ so that both $y_0>f(x)$ for all $x\in B_\delta(p)$ and $y_0< f(x)$ for some $x\in B_\delta(p)$ for $\delta$ appropriate you get a contradiction - that doesn't make sense

Comment: Okay, but I was trying to do a proof by contradiction. Since I arrived at one I guessed it was okay.

Comment: Indeed, but in your proof you should replace the $\limsup f$ by $y_0$, not replace $y$ by $y_0$. What you have shown is that there is no number $y_0$ so that $y_0<\limsup f$ and $y_0>\limsup f$. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: I am not sure I do. Did you have a look at the other questions? The $y_{0}$ is supposed to be $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}g(\epsilon)=\limsup_{x\to p}f(x)$ $,g(\epsilon):=\sup\{f(x)|x\in E\cap B_{\epsilon}(a)\setminus\{a\}\}$, for which I guess one can show $a)$ and $b)$ too. But then, if they are not equal I arrive at the above contradiction.